# transfer event from one dom to other dom in javascript

Tags: javascript, events

In javascript, let say I got two nodes(node A, node B). when I click on node A, can I transfer "click" event to node B, so event handler for node B will execute.

Answer (score 4):

Triggering a click event is fairly easy on buttons and other input elements, they have a `click()` method:

```
elementA.onclick = function () { elementB.click(); }
```

It's slightly more complicated with other events or elements that don't support the `click` method, you need to trigger the event using [`fireEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(VS.85).aspx) or [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent), depending on the browser:

```
elementA.onclick = function () {
    var elementB = document.getElementById("elementB");
    if ("dispatchEvent" in elementB) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elementB.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else if ("fireEvent" in elementB)
        elementB.fireEvent("onclick");
}
```

Comment: But what if you do not know what type of events are currently attached to an element and still want to transfer them to another element. Do the elements tracks attached events in some inner data structure?

Comment: @jayarjo: nope.  You could write your own method which would attach the event handler and keep a reference to the element, the function and the event type.  jQuery does this for events you attach using its methods.